# Special .bed to .fa conversion (GenomicCoordinates/DNAsequence)

Tags: python, r, bash, bioinformatics

My aim is to create a custom protein sequence reference file (**protein.fa**) from genomic coordinates (**origin.bed**).

(origin.bed; with Chromosome, start, end, TranscriptID, strand, GeneID)

```
chr1    109202569       109202584       ENST00000370031.1_uORF_0        -       ENSG00000162639.11
chr1    109203584       109203617       ENST00000370031.1_uORF_0        -       ENSG00000162639.11
chr11   102188276       102188302       ENST00000263464.3_uORF_0        +       ENSG00000023445.9
chr11   10830291        10830306        ENST00000530211.1_uORF_1        -       ENSG00000110321.11
chr11   10830400        10830451        ENST00000530211.1_uORF_0        -       ENSG00000110321.11
```

Desired two step output: genomic nucleotide sequence file (**nucleotide.fa**; 0-based) and protein sequence file (**protein.fa**).

(Illustration; Sequences do not fit to the coordinates in the snippet)

```
>chr1:109202569-109203617(ENST00000370031.1_uORF_0)
TCACCCGGAACAGATTTTTTCCTCCTTGGATGACTCCGTCATGGACAC
>chr11:102188276-102188302(ENST00000263464.3_uORF_0)
nucleotide sequence xyz
>chr11:10830291-10830306(ENST00000263464.3_uORF_0)
nucleotide sequence xyz
>chr11:10830400-10830451(ENST00000263464.3_uORF_0)
nucleotide sequence xyz
```

```
>chr1:109202569-109203617(ENST00000370031.1_uORF_0)
SPGTDFFLLGULRHGH
>chr11:102188276-102188302(ENST00000263464.3_uORF_0)
protein sequence xyz
...
```

An important point is that entries with the same TranscriptID should be concatenated prior to protein sequence translation. As illustrated for chr1 TranscriptID entries, there are two coordinate pairs (**origin.bed**; length: 15 and 33), which should form one sequence. A GeneID based concatenation is not possible, as TranscriptIDs can be different for the same GeneID (Last two entries for chr11), which would lead to faulty sequences.
Furthermore, the sequences should be strand-specific, by which (-) stranded sequences need to be reverse complemented for the **nucleotide.fa**.

My attempt to obtain the nucleotide sequences was based on **bedtools getfasta** (https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html). However, as seen in the doc, the desired output is not possible, but is really necessary for my downstream quality control.

Conversion of a **sample **nucleotide.fa**** does work straightforward with **faTrans**. Therefore, I really appreciate any ideas on how to convert the **origin.bed** to **nucleotide.fa**. Are you aware of any other packages or conversion tools that would be suitable?

Thank you!

Comment: Any of the languages you put in tags can do it (text manipulation), AFAIK there is no package or tool that does exactly that.  That being said, SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: If you do not get an answer here quickly, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My question is formulated to particularly ask for certain packages of the tagged languages or other tools, basically asking for more experience. No request for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation for [bedtools getfasta](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html) that you linked, it would appear that it would do what you want, with the `-s` option to reverse complement the features on the (-) strand and the `-split` option to concatenate the exons of the same transcript.

You would first need to convert your BED file to the ["BED12"](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/general-usage.html#bed-format) format with one line per transcript, that bedtools getfasta expects when running with the `-split` option.

You could write your own code to do this transformation or use a script like [bed6ToBed12](https://github.com/muhligs/bed6ToBed12). Here's an example with it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1, $2, $3, gensub(/_.*/, "", 1, $4), 0, $5}' origin.bed |\
bed6Tobed12.sh -i stdin > origin.bed12
```

(The AWK invocation in front is just to convert your input file to proper BED6 format, where the strand is the 6th field, and to extract the transcript name into the 4th field.)

After this you could run bedtools getfasta to get the nucleotide sequences:

```
bedtools getfasta -fi reference.fa -bed origin.bed12 -s -name -split > nucleotide.fa
```

Comment: Great, the bed6Tobed12 already performs the concatenation of similar TranscriptIDs. Thanks for bringing up the bed6 and bed12 conversion. It really helped a lot!